# ViewController Does Not have member named "allValues"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller

This is kind of a common question, but I could not find an answer that solved my specific issue.  I am creating a program that takes in a user entered credit card and returns the type of credit card.  Everything seems to check out except I keep getting the error "ViewController does not have a member names 'allValues'. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var typeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var creditCardTextField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func CardTypePressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    enum CardType: String {
        case None = "None"
        case Visa = "Visa"
        case AmericanExpress = "American Express"
        case Mastercard = "Mastercard"
        case Discover = "Discover"

        private func regularExpression() -> NSRegularExpression {
            switch self {
            case .Visa:
                return NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$", options: nil, error: nil)!
            case .AmericanExpress:
                return NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^3[47][0-9]{13}$", options: nil, error: nil)!
            case .Mastercard:
                return NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$", options: nil, error: nil)!
            case .Discover:
                return NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12}$", options: nil, error: nil)!
            default:
                return NSRegularExpression(pattern: ".*", options: nil, error: nil)!
            }
        }
        func isValidFor(cardNumber: String) -> Bool {
            let re = self.regularExpression()
            let range = NSRange(0..<cardNumber.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))
            let matches = re.numberOfMatchesInString(cardNumber, options: nil, range: range)
            return matches > 0
        }

        static let allValues = [Visa, AmericanExpress, Mastercard, Discover]
    }

     func from(cardNumber: String) -> CardType {
        for type in CardType.allValues {
            if type.isValidFor(cardNumber) {
                return type
            }
        }
        return CardType.None
    }
    var creditCardType = CardType.from(creditCardTextField).toRaw()
    typeLabel.text = "Credit Card Type: \(creditCardType)"

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no property `allValues` in `self`

You probably meant `CardType.allValues`. Something like this:

```
func from(cardNumber: String) -> CardType {
    for type in CardType.allValues {
        if type.isValidFor(cardNumber) {
            return type
        }
    }
    return CardType.None
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! That fixed that, but I ran into one more problem.  When trying to retrieve the type.  I run into a similar problem.  It says "CardType.Type does not have a member 'from'" Do you know what could be the problem here?  I added the code to the question.

Comment: @NickEmmons You should try to understand your code first... The `from` function is not part of the `CardType` enum. Check your code again an see if you can find the bug.

Comment: Alright so I've tried everything I would think would fix it but to no avail... Can you at least point me in the right direction for where this bug is?